# How do I copy a MySQL table from one server to another server via C# using mysql.data?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying a way to copy a table and his data from Server 1 to Server 2. If the table exists, drop the table before the copy. But I'm stuck and don't find any answer to continue. Plz, help.

```
        /*connect the two servers*/
        MySqlConnection conn_DB1 = new MySqlConnection(connString_DB1);
        MySqlConnection conn_DB2 = new MySqlConnection(connString_DB2);

        /*get the data from database.table on server 1*/
        MySqlDataAdapter adp_DB1 = new MySqlDataAdapter($"select * from {from_db}.{from_table}", conn_DB1);

        DataSet theDataSet_DB1 = new DataSet();
        adp_DB1.Fill(theDataSet_DB1, $"{from_db}.{from_table}");

        /*drop the database.table on server 2*/
        DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter adp_DB2 = new MySqlDataAdapter($"DROP TABLE {to_db}.{to_table}", conn_DB2);
        adp_DB2.Fill(tmp);

        /*How to: copy the schema and data from server 1 to server 2?*/
```

Comment: How did you make the database schema in the first place? You _could_ query it and reconstruct the commands, but it would be far easier to "mysqldump" (no need for c#) or run the original commands to create the schema on the new database. Also, probably don't want to drop items in the original database until you've completed the migration.

Comment: Also, do not use string concatenation to create sql commands. https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I know that is possible via mysqldump in server side. But I need in C# to use in a software side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solucion

1 - get the creation script from server 1

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE database.table
```

2- drop the table in the server 2

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS to_db.to_table
```

3- select the data from server 1 and populate server 2

```
select * from from_db.from_table
```

4 - A litle bit of code to change the table from to the new name and doing the register stuff;

```
 create_command.Replace($"CREATE TABLE `{from_table}`", $"CREATE TABLE `{to_table}`");

'INSERT INTO...'
```